# React Native debug release build with Metro

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, metro-bundler

I am working on a react-native application, when I run my debug build I am able to debug using the metro tool using the following commands.

```
npx react-native start 

npx react-native run-android
```

Magically my emulator pops up and if I click "d" in the metro terminal it activated my debugging tools.

When I run

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=release
```

When I click "d" in the metro terminal it says

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "devMenu" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
```

info Opening developer menu...

Is there something about the release build that does not allow for the use of these debugging tools or is there something I need to do within build.gradle or some other configuation file to enable using the metro debugger.

I am new to react-native development so my apologies if my terminology is off.

Appreciate you help!

Comment: As far as i know, you can't debug `release variant` . If you need to see something better check by using alert.

Comment: Thanks @Maneesh I appreciate your input. I have been getting the same feedback from others. The frustrating part is that my debug build is functioning as expected and the release build is not. So it's really tough to debug without the debugging tools.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by alert? Are you speaking of the javascript command or some specific react-native module?

Comment: May i know, exactly what are not working in production??? like js code or native plugins????

Comment: i am also facing this issue

Comment: debug build is fine but in release it blank screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After receiving feedback from various people on and off of SO it seems that the debugger is not meant to be used in the release build.

In my circumstance there was an issue with gradle configuration involving react-native-config which was a known issue related to Progaurd which would only impact release builds.

As recommended in this post I used the javascript alert() method to debug the issue.

Comment: Instead of alert you could use ‘debugger;’ this will set a breakpoint in your code so you can debug in the chrome dev tools (or any dev tools you have open)

Comment: Unfortunately you can not activate the debugger on the production build.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your device with Metro. Then you have to run this command

> npx react-native log-android

After that run the following command

> npx react-native run-android --variant=release

Your logs will appear in Metro console.